# How to show map using Bing Maps with long and lat values?

Tags: jquery, bing-maps, bing

I would like to call Bing Maps and pass the URL parameters and show the map based on longitude and latitude values, for example we can do this in Google maps https://www.google.com/maps?q=37.819722,-122.478611 so how do we achieve this using Bing maps? I need a simple URL that we can construct and pass the parameters of Long and Lat values so the map shows up, any code example would really help, I don't want to use API keys just a simple passing of parameters should do the trick, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do, see the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/articles/create-a-custom-map-url

Comment: Is there a way to automatically create a pin on the map at the given coordinate?

Comment: Yes, see the sp= parameter in the documentation linked above

Answer (score 0):

Another method to Use Bing Map Using Latitude and Longitude Coordinates.
Please modify this url into your desired coordinates:

[https://www.bing.com/maps/?cp=14.473131~120.973784&lvl=17.5](https://www.bing.com/maps/?cp=14.473131%7E120.973784&lvl=17.5)

**Place your latitude coordinate after a series character cp= and place your longitude coordinate after a character ~
The &lvl character series defines zoom level. The higher the number means higher zoom level.**

Another reference is use other Coordinates Locator website such as https://gps-coordinates.org/.

Please modify this url into your desired coordinates:
https://gps-coordinates.org/my-location.php?lat=14.4731326&lng=120.9737787

**Place your latitude coordinate after lat= and put your longitude coordinate after &lng=**

This website can show address name of the GPS coordinates.